# Sliding iterator skipping elements?

Tags: scala

I have a function defined as follows (simplified for the sake of argument):

```
def sendRecords(records: Iterator[Map[String, String]]) = {
    records.sliding(10,10).foreach { case recordList => println(recordList) } 
}
```

When I call this function, I can see from the println (and from knowing what the expected answer is) that the recordList's are indeed a batch of 10, but somehow certain items from 'records' seem to get skipped. The output, for this case, is missing the 1st, 12th, 13nd, 24th, 25th, ... (i.e. there seems to be some odd regularlity). Note that each single element is a map of string-> string (and the content is confidential), but for the sake of illustration, a simplified form of the output could be

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],[....]
```

for the batched case and

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19],[....]
```

for the case with "toList.iterator" (see below), which would be expected. In these outputs I have replaced the maps by an index that identifies them.

I have absolutely no idea why that could be happening. Note that 'records' is an iterator I implemented myself (i.e. with hasNext and next) - which I suspect matters. The implementation is quite complicated, though. I've added the main part of at the bottom.

Some indications that it is correct, though, are that

```
records.toList.iterator.sliding(10,10).foreach { case recordList => println(recordList) }
```

works fine and that

```
records.foreach { println }
```

also looks as expected (i.e. it prints every element individually, and the list is complete).

Would anyone know what's up here - or suggest some other things I could try? Any help would be much appreciated. I am using scala 2.10.5.

(Note that, whilst the toList.iterator hack works, it is not acceptable here as that would construct the entire list in memory, which will be way too big in production).

Thanks!
-Joris.

The iterator isn't quite tidied up yet, so forgive some potentially dodgy code (which may perhaps have caused this problem), but its idea is to iterate through a comma-separated file (i.e. the "lines" input) that has a fairly complex header definition (hence the state-approach). I cannot show the decoder, as that is confidential, but I hope this should be enough. Perhaps there is a flaw in my hasNext/next.

```
class DecodingIterator(lines: Iterator[String]) extends Iterator[Map[String, String]] {
  val decoder = new StatefulDecoder()
  var cachedRecord = Map[String,String]()

  def hasNext: Boolean = {
    if (!lines.hasNext || decoder.inState(decoder.Finished()))
        false
    else {
      while(!decoder.inState(decoder.Data())) {
        decoder.processLine(lines.next)
      }
      decoder.processLine(lines.next)
      cachedRecord = decoder.lastRecord
      !decoder.inState(decoder.Finished())
    }
  }

  def next = cachedRecord
}
```

Comment: can you provide your iterator implementation, expected output and real output?

Comment: You should indeed add the code of your `records` iterator. Unrelated, you can replace `sliding(10, 10)` with `grouped(10)`.

Comment: Yup, I've added the main bit of the iterator. It has a dependency on "StatefulDecoder" which I can't unfortauntely show. But what's there now should hopefully illustrate the hasNext/next logic sufficiently.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps "it.hasNext" is called more than once prior to "it.next()". As you can see from my implementation, calling it.hasNext() repeatedly is not idempotent.

Comment: @JorisPeeters That is indeed what is happening, before every slice `hasNext` is called two times, so you lose 1 element.

Comment: @JorisPeeters you have it right, I think.  You need to add a flag saying either cachedrecord has an as-yet-unrequested entry, and if it has, just return `true` from hasNext. (and reset theflag when next is called)

Comment: Thanks everyone - fixing up the hasNext method. Thanks also for the referal to 'grouped' - that is much neater indeed.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments to the question, the problem was with the implementation of the iterator, which did not behave idem-potently on 'hasNext' (and 'sliding' causes this to be called more than once in a row).

After fixing that, everything works fine.
Thanks for the help, everyone.